# How to check browser cookies support with Pyramid

Tags: python, cookies, session-cookies, pyramid

I would like to know, when is the right moment and how to check the browser cookies support.

I understand I have to check the next request and for instance, with beaker, looking for the session key `_creation_time` or `request.headers['Cookie']`... and raise an exception if not found but I don't want to do that or something similar for every request. Some parts of my application don't require cookies, like the home page or info, faq page...

When a user logs out, the session gets deleted or invalidated and I used to redirect to the home view, if I check the `session key` at that moment, I'll not find it but it doesn't mean there is this issue.

An example I used at the beginning of login view:

```
 try: request.headers['Cookie']
 except KeyError:
   return HTTPFound(location=request.route_url('home'))
```

Please also note that if I try to print an error message using `request.session.flash(msg, 'error')` or use the snippet again at the beginning of the home view and render a message with the template using a control return variable, after logout it will be erroneous displayed.

I am looking for the most elegant way to resolve issue...maybe subscribe to a event?...write down a function to call in some interested view?

Answer (score 3):

There are a few things that could the cause of your problems.

Before I continue... FYI Pyramid uses WebOb to handle request and response objects

- [WebOb Overview](http://docs.webob.org/en/latest/reference.html)
- [WebOb Class Documentation](http://docs.webob.org/en/latest/modules/webob.html)

**Scenario 1**

If you call set_cookie under Pyramid , and then do a redirect, the set_cookie will not be sent.  This is because redirects create a new response object.

There are a few ways around this:

1. The most straightforward is to just copy response headers into the cookie when you raise/return a redirect

   ```
   return HTTPfound( "/path/to/redirect", headers=[ (k,v) for (k,v)\
   in self.request.response.headers.iteritems() if k == 'Set-Cookie']  )
   ```

   OR

   ```
   resp = HTTPFound(location='/path/to/redirect') 
   return self.request.response.merge_cookies(resp)
   ```

   I should also note that MOST browsers accept cookies on redirects, however Safari does not.
2. another way is to use pyramid's hooks to convert cookies behind the scenes.  i wrote subscribers that automate this.  they're on pypi and github. https://github.com/jvanasco/pyramid_subscribers_cookiexfer

**Scenario 2**

There are two ways of handling sessions in Pyramid.  Pyramid has its own session library, and then there is [Beaker](http://readthedocs.org/docs/pyramid_beaker/en/latest), which handled [sessions](http://beaker.readthedocs.org/en/latest/modules/session.html) for Pylons and has Pyramid support that many people use.  I can't speak of `pyramid.session`, but Beaker has two modes to kill the session:

```
delete()
Delete the cookie, and clear the session

invalidate()
Clear the contents and start a new session
```

If you call `invalidate()`, the Beaker session cookie stays the same and all the session data is cleared -- so you can start storing new data into an empty session object.

If you call `delete()`, the cookie gets killed as does the session data.  If you put new information into the session, IIRC, it will go into a new sessionid / cookie .  However, as I noted in the first part above, `set_cookie` will get called but then thrown out during the redirect.  So if you `delete()` the session and then don't migrate the set_cookie headers... the client will never receive a session identifier.

**Some example behaviors of cookies under pyramid**

Behavior of redirect

- User visits site and is given cookie: SessionId=1
- User clicks login

  - App saves login status to session "1"
  - App calls set_cookie with "LoggedIn=1"
  - App calls redirect to /home
  - Redirect sent, no cookies
- User lands on /home

  - App only sees cookie for "SessionId=1"

Behavior of delete with redirect:

- User clicks logout

  - App calls 'delete()' on session, killing the datastore and placing a set_cookie in request.response to expire the old cookie.  if a new sessionid is created, that is sent as well.
  - If app renders a response, then client receives cookies
  - If app redirects, client does not receive headers to expire the cookie or set up a new one

Behavior of invalidate with redirect:

- User clicks logout

  - App calls 'invalidate()' on session, killing the datastore
  - App sets a custom "loggedout=0" cookie
  - If app renders a response, then client receives cookies
  - If app redirects:

    - Client does not receive "loggedout=0" header
    - Client still has the old session cookie, but it was invalidated/purged on the backend, so they are effectively locked out.

side note: I personally don't like using the `request.headers` interface -- which handles all headers -- to get at cookies.  I've had better luck with `request.cookies` -- which returns a dictionary of cookies.